# Telerik Kendo dropdownlist remove item

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I have a kendo dropdownlist which options looks like the following:

```
$scope.addressDropdownOptions = {

    dataSource: $scope.customerAddress,
    dataTextField: "Address.PrId",
    dataValueField: "PrId",

    headerTemplate: '<div style="width:100%;">' +
            '<span style="padding-left:5px; font-weight:bold;">City</span>' +
            '<span style="padding-left:129px; font-weight:bold;">Address</span>' +
            '<span style="padding-left:107px; font-weight:bold;">Note</span>' +
            '</div>',

    valueTemplate: '<span>{{dataItem.Address.City}} </span>' +
                   '<span>{{dataItem.Address.Street}}</span>',

    template: '<div style="width:100%;">' +
                    '<div class="customerDropDown">{{dataItem.Address.City}}</div>' +
                    '<div class="customerDropDown">{{dataItem.Address.Street}}</div>' +
                    '<div class="customerDropDown">{{dataItem.Address.Note}}</div> </div>',

};
```

The user has the option to select one, and then hit a button, which is supposed to remove the selected item from the dropdownlist.

So I'm doing the following:

```
$scope.customerAddress.splice(i, 1);
```

Now the selected item is not an option anymore in the dropdown, BUT - the valueTemplate is still showing the removed item. I'd like that to be the first index of $scope.customerAddress.

Another problem is that the first option in the new list, can not be selected. When I click it, the valueTemplate still results in the previously removed item.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove item directly from the source object (in your case, `$scope.customerAddress`), the dropDownList won't be aware of that change.  If you want to remove an item, it has to be done using the dataSource's [remove function](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/dropdownlist/how-to/remove-items):

```
var ddl =  $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");
var oldData = ddl.dataSource.data();
ddl.dataSource.remove(oldData[0]); //remove first item
```